# What resources do blocked threads take-up

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

One of the main purposes of writing code in the asynchronous programming model (more specifically - using callbacks instead of blocking the thread) is to minimize the number of blocking threads in the system.

For running threads , this goal is obvious, because of context switches and synchronization costs.

But what about blocked threads? why is it so important to reduce their number?

For example, when waiting for a response from a web server a thread is blocked and doesn't take-up any CPU time and does not participate in any context switch.

So my question is:
other than RAM (about 1MB per thread ?) What other resources do blocked threads take-up?

And another more subjective question:
In what cases will this cost really justify the hassle of writing asynchronous code (the price could be, for example, splitting your nice coherent method to lots of beginXXX and EndXXX methods, and moving parameters and local variables to be class fields).

UPDATE - additional reasons I didn't mention or didn't give enough weight to:

1. More threads means more locking on communal resources
2. More threads means more creation and disposing of threads which is expensive
3. The system can definitely run-out of threads/RAM and then stop servicing clients (in a web server scenario this can actually bring down the service)

Comment: Quibble: The answer may depend upon context. E.g., IIS worker threads are a limited commodity, whereas OS threads are less so. Detail would be helpful.

Comment: I've never heard minimizing the number of existing threads to be a purpose of asynchronous code. Asynchronous code, by definition, relies on having more threads than synchronous (single threaded!) code.

Comment: @Harper: [Disagree.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/04/asynchrony-in-c-5-0-part-four-it-s-not-magic.aspx)

Comment: By the way IIS Threads by default have a stack of only 256Kb not the default 1Meg.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: My main point is that limiting the number of threads in use is not a _reason_ to use asynchronous methods.

Comment: @Harper: I disagree as well, that's the number one reason to use BeginXxx methods.  They very often use overlapped I/O instead of a thread to get the job done.  *Much* cheaper.

Comment: @Hans Passant: *how* asynchronous code is implemented may affect the number of threads in the system, but the *reason* for writing asynchronous code is not to reduce thread count.

Comment: @Harper Shelby: Take a look at this post from MSDN magazine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx

Comment: @rony l: So, the part in the article that says "users use async methods to avoid creating threads" is the part I'm supposed to read, as opposed to this code:  // Use a thread pool thread to perform the operation
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoTaskHelper, ar); ? So, the *user* of this class doesn't use or create a thread, but the implementation of the async method does, and this is better than the user queuing up a work item? It **didn't change the number of threads used by the application at all**.

Comment: @Harper Shelby: The APM point is this: Does the thread that initiated the I/O operation or computation block until the work he initiated completes? If it does, there's currently one more thread in the system which is in blocking state. APM enables the "calling" thread to be released and the work will be done in the callback once the operation completes.

Comment: @rony l: Yes, I get that. What I disagree with is the contention that asynchronous programming is done **to minimize the number of existing threads in the system**. That is completely orthogonal to the purpose of asynchronous programming.

Comment: @Harper Shelby: you're absolutely right. I changed the word existing to blocking in the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So my question is: other than RAM (about 1MB per thread ?) What other resources do blocked threads take-up?

This is one of the largest ones.  That being said, there's a reason that the ThreadPool in .NET allows so many threads per core - in 3.5 [the default was 250 worker threads per core in the system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(VS.90).aspx). (In .NET 4, it depends on system information such as virtual address size, platform, etc. - there isn't a fixed default now.)  Threads, especially blocked threads, really aren't that expensive...

However, I would say, from a code management standpoint, it's worth reducing the number of blocked threads.  Every blocked thread is an operation that should, at some point, return and become unblocked.  Having many of these means you have quite a complicated set of code to manage.  Keeping this number reduced will help keep the code base simpler - and more maintainable.

> And another more subjective question: In what cases will this cost really justify the hassle of writing asynchronous code (the price could be, for example, splitting your nice coherent method to lots of beginXXX and EndXXX methods, and moving parameters and local variables to be class fields).

Right now, it's often a pain.  It depends a lot on the scenario.  The `Task<T>` class in .NET 4 dratically improves this for many scenarios, however.  Using the TPL, it's much less painful than it was previously using the APM (BeginXXX/EndXXX) or even the EAP.

This is why the language designers are putting so much effort into [improving this situation in the future](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=18712f38-fcd2-4e9f-9028-8373dc5732b2).  Their goals are to make async code much simpler to write, in order to allow it to be used more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from any resources the blocked thread might hold a lock on, thread pool size is also of consideration. If you have reached the maximum thread pool size (if I recall correctly for .NET 4 is max thread count is 100 per CPU) you simply won't be able to get anything else to run on the thread pool until at least one thread gets freed up.

Comment: @Reed: Interesting - do you have a link for me so I can read up on that? Also does that mean there is *no* maximum thread count at all anymore? Certainly spawning new threads would have a start-up cost at the very least.

Comment: There is a limit, but its based on system address space.  on x64, for example, it's huge.  For info on the CLR 4 thread pool, see: http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2009/06/net-clr-thread-pool-work.html  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that the 1MB figure for stack memory (or 256KB, or whatever it's set to) is a reserve; while it does take away from available address space, the actual memory is only committed as it's needed.

On the other hand, having a very large number of threads is bound to bog down the task scheduler somewhat as it has to keep track of them (which have become runnable since the last tick, and so on).

Comment: This isn't true in managed code, the CLR commits the entire stack.  There's a Chris Brumme blog post that documents this.  Joe Duffy blogged about it too.  Seek and ye shall find.

Comment: I was unaware of this. That is lame, IMHO.

Comment: This is no longer true either, apparently. The default commit size for a thread in .Net Framework is now 100KB. However, I can't find any documentation about .Net Core's behaviour. With 64-bit address spaces 1MB of reserved space is almost nothing.